# How to show the right thumbnail on facebook when a user shares a link?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am having trouble getting the right thumbnail to appear when a user shares a link from site on their facebook page.

For the first site it works fine: videomuncher.com/youtube/PN-MjUC4f9k/

However, for this site it doesn't: videomuncher.com/partner/Sports/GrantlandNetwork/wadUaPuohfE/#wadUaPuohfE

Looking at the source for each page, I think I'm defining the right attributes for facebook to pick up (link, picture, name, etc) but when I use the facebook debugger, it gives me errors.  Any advice?

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fvideomuncher.com%2Fpartner%2FSports%2FGrantlandNetwork%2FwadUaPuohfE%2F%23wadUaPuohfE

Comment: Try putting your OG meta tags further up in the document – currently, you have them quite a way down, and Facebook’s scraper likes to read only the first _x_ byte of a document and expects them to be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the debugger, facebook can't find it from your page meta-data tags. You need to specify og:image in your page meta-data tags, e.g:

```
<meta property="og:image"  content="address to the thumbnail" />
```

Comment: I've specified this on the page.  <meta property="og:image" content="http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/wadUaPuohfE/hqdefault.jpg"/> It's at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fvideomuncher.com%2Fpartner%2FSports%2FGrantlandNetwork%2FwadUaPuohfE%2F%23wadUaPuohfE which is what facebook sees when it scrapes the url.

Comment: why did you put them in the SCRIPT tang?! they should be inside <head> </head> tag!